# Calculate Total Pipeline latency (Cloud Functions -> Pub/Sub -> Dataflow -> BQ)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver

I currently have a pipeline in GCP that ingests data using a Cloud function, deposits it into PubSub, processes it in Dataflow, and finally inserts it into BigQuery. I'm trying to calculate how long it takes an average message to travel from Cloud Function ingestion to BigQuery (including insertion time).

I'm aware of Stackdriver metrics/dashboards as well as GCP's API Dashboards. I'm tempted to simply add up all latency values for each service, but I'm not sure that it covers latency outside my control (ex. insertion to BQ, pushing from dataflow to pubsub, etc...)

What available metrics can help me calculate overall pipeline latency? If a part of the pipeline cannot be accounted for, is there a way to estimate it or use an external tool to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow shows a metric called 'System Lag', which expresses the end-to-end latency for the Dataflow pipeline. This should help you have a notion of latency for the PubSub(output) -> Dataflow -> BQ section of the pipeline.

Though I have not used it myself, you could use Stackdriver Trace to trace some events from your Cloud Function, and trace the same event when it's ingested by Dataflow. This would allow you to have a measure of the latency for the Cloud Functions -> PubSub(in) -> PubSub(output) section of the pipeline.

LMK if that seems like an interesting path to look into, and we can try to build up from that.

Comment: It makes sense that System Lag includes time from pubsub to Dataflow, but to confirm, it also includes BQ insertion time? I wasn't aware of Stackdriver Trace! I'll look into it and let you know how it works out!